Alternative way to verify that a bilinear form is degenerate
Definition 1: Let $f$ be a bilinear form over $V$. $f$ is degenerate if $det[f]_B=0$ for some/all basis $B$ of $V$.
Definition 2: $f$ is non-degenerate if $f(x,y)=0$ for all $x\in V$ implies $y=0$.

Let $V=\mathbb{R}[x]_{\leq 2}$.
Consider the bilinear form $$f(p,q)=\int_{-1}^{1}xp(x)q(x)dx.$$ Determine if $f$ is degenerate.
$B=\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}=\{ 1,x,x^2\}$ is basis of $V$. Notice that $v_k=x^{k-1}$. Let $A:=[f]_B$. Each entry $a_{ij}=f(v_i,v_j)$. Eventually, we get that $$A=[f]_B=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 2/3 &0\\
2/3 & 0 & 2/5\\
0 & 2/5& 0
\end{pmatrix}$$ and clearly $det(A)=0$. So $f$ is degenerate.
When I first attempted the exercise,I tried to verify that it is degenerate using the negation of Definition 2, but I couldn't so I gave up and proceeded to verify that $f$ indeed satisfied Definition 1. But now, Im revisiting my solution of this exercise and I'm wondering again if it's possible to verify that $f$ is degenerate using the negation of Definition 2.

Pick a nonzero $y$ in the kernel of your matrix $A$, for example $y=(3,0-5)^T$. Then we have for all $x$ that $$f(x,y)=x^T A y=x^T (0,0,0)^T=0.$$ However, $y$ is nonzero and therefore $f$ is not non-degenerate.

We have to find $p(x)=a+bx+cx^2$ such that $(a,b,c)\neq (0,0,0)$ and for all polynomials $q(x)$ of degree $\leq 2$, we have $f(p,q)=0$.
In fact a quick observation with symmetry (or simply looking at which columns of your matrix are the dependent ones) tells us we should set $b=0$ and consider $p(x)=a+cx^2$. Now,

if $q(x)=1$ or $q(x)=x^2$, then we have $f(p,q)=\int_{-1}^1x(a+cx^2)q(x)\,dx=0$ due to the integrand being an odd function and the domain $[-1,1]$ being symmetric about the origin.
for $q(x)=x$, we have $f(p,q)=\int_{-1}^1x(a+cx^2)x\,dx=2\int_0^1x^2(a+cx^2)\,dx=\frac{2a}{3}+\frac{2c}{5}$, which is exactly what you’d expect by looking at the first and third columns of your matrix. Now, we would like for this to be $0$, so this happens if and only if $c=-\frac{5a}{3}$.

Thus, for any $a\in\Bbb{R}$, if we set $p(x)=a+\left(-\frac{5a}{3}\right)x^2$, or more simply if we set $p(x)=a(3-5x^2)$, then the above reasoning shows that for $q(x)\in \{1,x,x^2\}$, we have $f(p,q)=0$. So, by linearity, this holds for all the polynomials $q(x)$. So, if you want a concrete polynomial to negate definition (2), then you can consider $p(x)=3-5x^2$; this is non-zero but $f(p,\cdot)=0$ (you can also take any non-zero multiple of this $p(x)$).

Thanks for the detailed answer! I feel better now that I understand how to solve this exercise using both definitions instead of only one definition

You want to find a nonzero polynomial $q\in V$ such that $\forall p\in V\;f(p,q)=0$, i.e. $\int_{-1}^1x^kq(x)dx=0$ for $k=1,2,3$.
$$\int_{-1}^1x^k(ax^2+bx+c)dx=\begin{cases}\frac2{k+2}b,&k=1\text{ or }3\\\frac25a+\frac23c,&k=2\end{cases}$$
so, a solution is
$$q(x)=5x^2-3.$$

Nice approach, very straightforward. Thanks!
